# Geolookup System

Tags: database, math, geolocation, coords

*I'm not too sure what the best place for this is*

I'm working on an app that requires me to find points of interest thats within a specific radius of a users location.

For example, I grab the users location as Lat and Long coordinates and want to find all the items within a 20 mile radius.

Right now I have a MySQL database with 450,000 records with each record containing a Lat and Long. I then run a prepared statement to grab X amount of records within a 20 meter radius.

This is quite slow and intensive on the database.

Are there better ways to optimise lookups when using MySQL or is there a purpose built system?
Right now this is a hobby project so affording a service that does this may be out of my $0 budget.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Could you post A) one slow query, B) EXPLAIN (slowquery); C) SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_name-with-450000-records); and D) SHOW INDEX FROM (tbl_name); E) the prepared statement doing the grab x records?

Comment: We would like to help you.  Without requested information, assistance will not be possible.